# Questions about using mathematical methods to prove the Caratheodory's Concept of Temperature

Tags: physics

First
This is what I have saw in a thermodynamics textbook:

///////////////////Start of discussion/////////////////////

"There are three homogeneous system,and their parameters of the equation of state:

$O=f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$

$P=g(y_1,\ldots,y_m)$

$Q=h(z_1,\ldots,z_k)$

If $O=P$, there must be a function $F$,$F(x_1,\ldots,x_n;y_1,\ldots,y_m)=0$ 
So that,if $P=Q$ and $O=Q$,then:

$G(x_1,\ldots,x_n;z_1,\ldots,z_k)=0$

$H(y_1,\ldots,y_n;z_1,\ldots,z_k)=0$

Let $\frac{∂F}{x_1}≠0$ and $\frac{∂G}{x_1}≠0$,then From $F(x_1,\ldots,x_n;y_1,\ldots,y_m)=0$ and $G(y_1,\ldots,y_n;z_1,\ldots,z_k)=0$ we can find $x_1$:

$x_1=F_1(y_1,\ldots,y_m;x_2,\ldots,x_n)=0$

$x_1=G_1(z_1,\ldots,z_k;x_2,\ldots,x_n)=0$

$F_1=G_1$

In this case,$H(y_1,\ldots,y_m;z_1,\ldots,z_k)=0$ if and only if $F_1$ and $G_1$ is this form:

$F_1=a(x_2,\ldots,x_n)s(y_1,\ldots,y_m)+b(x_2,\ldots,x_n)$

$G_1=a(x_2,\ldots,x_n)r(z_1,\ldots,z_k)+b(x_2,\ldots,x_n)$

Let $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\frac{x_1-b(x_2,\ldots,x_n)}{a(x_2,\ldots,x_n)}$,then:

$f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=s(y_1,\ldots,y_m)=r(z_1,\ldots,z_k)$

///////////////////////end of discussion//////////////////////

So I have some questions about this discussion:

① why $x_1=F_1(y_1,\ldots,y_m;x_2,\ldots,x_n)=G_1(z_1,\ldots,z_k;x_2,\ldots,x_n)=0$,when $\frac{∂F}{x_1}≠0$ and $\frac{∂G}{x_1}≠0$?

② why $F_1$ and $G_1$ have to be that form in the discussion?

③why we can let $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\frac{x_1-b(x_2,\ldots,x_n)}{a(x_2,\ldots,x_n)}$,why we have to do this?

④Is $g(y_1,\ldots,y_m)=s(y_1,\ldots,y_m)$ and $h(z_1,\ldots,z_k)=r(z_1,\ldots,z_k)$,in other words,is $s(y_1,\ldots,y_m)$ and $r(z_1,\ldots,z_k)$ are the equation of state of $P$ and $Q$?

I have post this question on mathoverflow section now 
(https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327369/questions-about-using-mathematical-methods-to-prove-the-caratheodorys-concept-o)